# Roblox Animation not playing (Lua)

Tags: animation, lua, roblox

I exported FBX animation to Roblox Animator Plugin. In plugin, it was playing perfectly fine, but when I wrote script

```
local model = script.Parent     
local animControl = model.AnimationController

local idleAnim = animControl:LoadAnimation(script.IdleAnim)
idleAnim.Looped = true

idleAnim:Play()
```

The animation is not playing.
I'd like to post this on Roblox DevForum, but they made it impossible to post anything because of "level up" system.
Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sn928nkBOrc&list=LL&index=1&t=365s 
This is the tutorial I use

Comment: Are there any errors being thrown? Is this a Script or a LocalScript? Is `AnimationController` the model's Humanoid or an AnimationController you've added?

Comment: @Kylaaa It does not show any errors, and I added ```AnimationController``` by myself, not through ```Humanoid```. I used built-in **Avatar Importer** plugin. And this is global script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some testing, I found out that **exactly exported from FBX animations** are not playing. But my hand-made animations are playing.
Still didn't figure out why, I will edit this post whenever I do.



EDIT: nevermind, it started working. Looks like it was bug.